# PDF COSDictionary with key names like L, O, E, N, T, andH

Tags: pdfbox

When I looked into the Apache Java pdfbox parser code, the first dictionary has key names of single characters and values of simple integers. For example, there can be an entry like `(COSName{N}:COSInt{606})`, another entry like `(COSName{T}:COSInt{3423924})` in the dictionary.

There must be some pre-defined meaning of these single-character key names. Why are the values simple integers? Could someone please provide more insights as to what they mean? Are they some offsets or codes defined by PDF specs?

Comment: What you saw are the entries for a linearized file, which is ignored by PDFBox (except in preflight).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISO 32000-1:2008 specification includes tables for known dictionary entries, they typically list a column for **Key**, Type, and **Value**.  This usually includes an explanation of the meaning of the key and sometimes explicitly mentions allowed values.

### O key

E.g. **Section 12.3.5 Collections** shows in *Table 157 – Entries in a collection field dictionary*:

```
O
integer
(Optional) The relative order of the field name in the user interface. Fields shall be sorted by the conforming reader in ascending order.
```

However such keys can have different meanings in different dictionaries.

E.g. **Section 7.6.3.2 Standard Encryption Dictionary** shows in *Table 21 - Additional encryption dictionary entries for the standard security handler*:

```
O
string
(Required) A 32-byte string, based on both the owner and user passwords, that shall be used in computing the encryption key and in determining whether a valid owner password was entered. For more information, see 7.6.3.3, "Encryption Key Algorithm," and 7.6.3.4, "Password Algorithms."
```

You should be able to find explanations there for such keys.

Comment: Thanks so much Joseph! Would you please elaborate on the value of an integer? For example, I see a key of Root with a value as COSObject{124333,0} is telling me? It will help me to study the specs.

Comment: Sorry hit return too quick. The description of a Root key says it is an indirect reference. It is the catalog dictionary for the PDF document contained in the file. So, does it mean the vlaue 124333 points to an indirect reference hat is the catalog? How do I cast the value to obtain the catalog itself?

Comment: open the PDF with NOTEPAD++ and look for "124333 0 obj". That is that indirect object. If you don't find it, then it is hidden in an object stream.